# Plot scatter graphs with matplotlib subplot

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to plot a scatter diagram. It will take multiple arrays as input but plot into a single graph.
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.gca()
n_p=np.array([17.2,25.7,6.1,0.9,0.5,0.2])   
n_d=np.array([1,2,3])
a_p=np.array([4.3,1.4,8.1,1.8,7.9,7.0])
a_d=np.array([12,13,14])

ax.scatter = ([n_d[0]/n_d[1]],[n_p[0]/n_p[1]])
ax.scatter = ([a_d[0]/a_d[1]],[a_p[0]/a_p[1]])
```

I will read the arrays from csv file, here I just put a simple example (for that I imported os). I want to plot the ratio of array element 2/ element 1 of n_p (as x-axis) and same with n_d (as y-axis). This will give a point in the graph. Similar operation will be followed by a_p and a_d array, and the point will be appended to the graph. There will be more data to append, but to understand the process, two is enough.
I tried to follow example from [here](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-plot-multiple-datasets-in-one-scatter-matplotlib-scatter-plot-in-python).
If I use the color, I get syntax error.
If I do not use color, I get a blank plot.

Sorry, my coding experience is beginner so code is rather nasty.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ax.scatter(...)` not `ax.scatter = (...)` this is a typo.  Call out typos in the comments, because question with typos are typically closed and deleted, as they aren't considered beneficial to the community.

Comment: thanks @TrentonMcKinney I have corrected it.

Comment: Don't correct the question, because the typo is what was causing the error it seems. Rolled back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the `=` from the function call!

```
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.gca()
n_p=np.array([17.2,25.7,6.1,0.9,0.5,0.2])   
n_d=np.array([1,2,3])
a_p=np.array([4.3,1.4,8.1,1.8,7.9,7.0])
a_d=np.array([12,13,14])

ax.scatter([n_d[0]/n_d[1]],[n_p[0]/n_p[1]])
ax.scatter([a_d[0]/a_d[1]],[a_p[0]/a_p[1]])
```

Comment: Could you tell me whats is the ax=plt.gca() mean?

Comment: it means return the axis that is currently focused, and if no axis exists then create one ... it's actually better to use something like `f, ax = plt.subplots()`  instead of `plt.gca()`